# Why implicit function theorem fails for a composite function?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

Suppose I have $ax +b =c$. I can solve $\partial x/\partial c$ by IFT assuming that $a,b$ are constants and $x,c$ are variables: let $F= ax +b -c$. Then, $$\partial x/\partial c = -F_c/F_x =1/a$$

Now it's also true that $e^{ax +b}= e^c $, but when I apply IFT to $F'=e^{ax +b}- e^c$, I get the wrong derivative:

$$\partial x/\partial c = -F'_c/F'_x =\frac{e^c}{a e^{ax+b}} \neq 1/a$$

Can you tell me where am I making a mistake in the calculations?

A montone transformation of both sides of the original equality should not change the result.

Comment: But that is $\frac 1a$ since $e^c=e^{ax+b}$.

Comment: Note:  it's hard to follow what you have written since it is hard to tell which terms are variables and which are constant.  I guess $c$ is a variable  (since you are differentiating with respect to $c$). But what of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: a,b,c are constants. So your comment solves my question. I think it would be nice to have a one or two lines proof that a monotone transformation of both sides of the equality doesn't matter for applying IFT.

Comment: That does not make sense.  If $a,b,c$ are constant, then so is $x$ (as it is equal to $\frac {c-b}a$).  Hence all deriviatives of $x$ must vanish.

Comment: I mean I want to study the derivative of x(a,b,c) defined implicitly by an equality, and  a,b,c are parameters.

Comment: So...$a,b,c$ aren't constant?  This is all very vague.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: In my comment I assumed that $a,b$ were constants and that $x, c$ were variables.  I don't see what else makes sense here.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to lulu's comment I solved my doubt.

Indeed $e^c = e^{ax + b}$ by my initial equality. So $-F'_c/F'_x = 1/a.$

A bit more generally, knowing that $$f(ax + b) = f(c),$$ we can compute $\partial x/ \partial c$ by applying IFT to $F' =f(ax + b) - f(c)$:

$$ \partial x/ \partial a = - \frac{-f'(c)}{f'(ax + b) a}= 1/a. $$

$f'(c) = f'(ax + b) $ follows by differentiating both sides of the first displayed equality.